# wp login redirects to homepage

Tags: wp-admin

wp login redirects to homepage just started to happen. I login to my admin area using /wp-admin no problem but instead of being redirect to the admin area i am redirected to a incomplete version of the frontpage. This started to happen no upgrades or new plugins or messing about with the back end

---

I have disabled all the plugins and its still happening - any other ideas

Answer (score 4):

Piggybacking on Denis's comment about the site's domain having changed....

if you can get access to the database (ie. if your host has phpmyadmin on its control panel) check the 'siteurl' option in the wp_options table of the database. If that option is set to an address that redirects or doesn't resolve, you won't be able to get into your admin section.

I've seen that sort of thing happen before when a hosting provider had a setting that redirected all requests from domain.url to www.domain.url, but the blog's 'siteurl' option was set as http://domain.url

Answer (score 2):

Tried to delete your cookies? Any chances you recently changed your site's domain (e.g. its www pref...)?

Comment: do you mean clear private data in the browser?

Comment: yeah. delete cookies, cached pages, etc. all of it. (or at least all of the cookies from that site's domain.)